# How to place bars in the correct place on a chart in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, charts

Hi I am currently trying to get the bars to be aligned over the the numbers in the x axis. As you can see in the image below, my bars in the chart seem to align to the left or right.

[URL=http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/528/stackoverflowexample.png/][IMG=http://img528.imageshack.us/img528/19/stackoverflowexample.png][/IMG][/URL]

Uploaded with [URL=http://imageshack.us]ImageShack.us[/URL]

I was wondering if there was a way using lines of code to make them align directly over the numbers 1, 2 and 3?

I also wondering if it is possible to change 1, 2 and 3 into the name temprature, vcc and light??

I have done some looking into it and am unable to find how to correct this problem (as you can see from the commented out lines of code were i have tried) and this is why i have turned to you guys.I have posted my code below ( slightly modified so it will work in any c# without my variables).

thanks for takin the time to read this

```
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("area");
                    //chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
                    //chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Maximum = 2;
                    //chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
                    //chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode;
                    chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
                    chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Maximum = sumLight + 100;
                    chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Interval = 50;
                    chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisY.Title = "Average Value";
                    //chart1.ChartAreas["area"].AxisX.Title = "Speed (m/s)";

                    chart1.Series.Add("Temprature");
                    chart1.Series.Add("VCC");
                    chart1.Series.Add("Light");

                    chart1.Series["Temprature"].Color = Color.Red;
                    chart1.Series["VCC"].Color = Color.Green;
                    chart1.Series["Light"].Color = Color.Yellow;

                    chart1.Series["Temprature"].Points.AddXY(1, 78.32);
                    chart1.Series["VCC"].Points.AddXY(2, 3.92);
                    chart1.Series["Light"].Points.AddXY(3, 333);
                    chart1.Series["Temprature"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    chart1.Series["VCC"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    chart1.Series["Light"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

                    chart1.Legends.Add("legend");
                    chart1.Titles.Add("Average for Temperature, Light & VCC using timestamp");


                    chart1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might come to something by inserting empty datapoints.
So this block :

```
chart1.Series["Temprature"].Points.AddXY(1, 78.32);
chart1.Series["VCC"].Points.AddXY(2, 3.92);
chart1.Series["Light"].Points.AddXY(3, 333);
```

Should become

```
chart1.Series["Temprature"].Points.AddXY(1, 78.32);
chart1.Series["Temprature"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(2,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series["Temprature"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(3,0){IsEmpty=true});

chart1.Series["VCC"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(1,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series["VCC"].Points.AddXY(2, 3.92);
chart1.Series["VCC"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(3,0){IsEmpty=true});

chart1.Series["Light"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(1,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series["Light"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(2,0){IsEmpty=true});
chart1.Series["Light"].Points.AddXY(3, 333);
```

Also, you might try having only one serie with 3 colored DataPoints :

```
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY("Temprature", 78.32);
chart1.Series[0].Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1].Color = Color.Red;
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY("VCC", 3.92);
chart1.Series[0].Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1].Color = Color.Green;
chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY("Light", 333);
chart1.Series[0].Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1].Color = Color.Yellow;
```